# Question about Elements of Statistical Learning - Section 11.7

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

This might be a very easy question but somehow I am stuck. In this chapter, Net-3 has 16x16 input layer and 8x8 first hidden layer. It is using local connectivity with 3x3 input patch. The receptive field of two neighboring units in the hidden layer overlap by 1 column/row, which looks like a stride of 2. But then, how does the number match up? Stride of 1 does not match up the number either. Is there any information I am missing in this process? Any help would be appreciated!

P.S. The book can be found [here](https://hastie.su.domains/Papers/ESLII.pdf).